# DRF APITestCase force_authenticate make request.user return tuple instead of User object

Tags: python, django, testing, django-rest-framework

I have a custom authentication class following the docs

```
class ExampleAuthentication(authentication.BaseAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, request):
        username = request.META.get('HTTP_X_USERNAME')
        if not username:
            return None

        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('No such user')

        return (user, None)
```

and I used it in my APIView:

```
class profile(APIView):
    permission_classes = ()
    authentication_classes = (ExampleAuthentication,)

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        try:
            print('user', request.user)
            serializer = GetUserSerializer(request.user)

            return JsonResponse({'code': 200,'data': serializer.data}, status=200)
        except Exception as e:
            return JsonResponse({'code': 500,'data': "Server error"}, status=500)
```

when I try to call it normally from the API through postman I got the following result from the print and it worked normally:

> user User(143)

I wrote a test using [force_authenticate()](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#force_authenticateusernone-tokennone):

```
class BaseUserAPITest(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
      # self.factory = APIRequestFactory()
      self.user = models.User.objects.get_or_create(
                username='test_user_1',
                uid='test_user_1',
                defaults={'agent_type': 1}
            )

    def test_details(self):
      url = reverse("api.profile")
      self.client.force_authenticate(user=self.user)
      response = self.client.get(url)
      self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

I got server error because the print of `request.user` return a tuple instead of a User object, this is the print from the test log

> user (<User: User(143)>, True)

I tried searching up and seem like there no result or explanation on why this happening

My version:

```
django==2.2.8
djangorestframework==3.10.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not `force_authenticate` but [`get_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) method. It returns tuple. First element of the tuple is object and second one is boolean indicating if object was created or not. To fix change your code in `setUp` method to this:

```
def setUp(self):
      # self.factory = APIRequestFactory()
      self.user, _ = models.User.objects.get_or_create(
                username='test_user_1',
                uid='test_user_1',
                defaults={'agent_type': 1}
            )
```

Comment: oh i see, that's why... i forgot about that. Thank for pointing out my mistake!